# Multiple SQL Joins from same table with Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have a DB with 2 columns of ID that reference the same table

How do I do 2 joins to the same table, and be able to pull the data.

Here is what I have:

```
$this->db->select('s.id, c.title, c.description, s.time ,s.day,s.instructor_change,s.studio_change,s.time_change,s.new_class,s.reservation_req,s.easy_does_it,s.mind,s.level,s.duration,s.location,i.first,i.last');
            $this->db->from('schedule as s');
            $this->db->join('instructors as i', 'i.id = s.instructor_id','inner');
            $this->db->join('classes as c', 'c.id = s.class_id');
            $this->db->where('s.active', '1');
            $this->db->where('s.day', $dayofweek);
            $this->db->order_by('s.time',"ASC");

            $query = $this->db->get();
```

I need to also pull something like this
$this->db->join('instructors as i', 'i.id = **s._alt_instructor_id**');

How do I join the same table twice, but be able to pull the in this case the first and last name again for a different ID on the same record?

**Answer**

```
$this->db->select('s.id, c.title, c.description, s.time ,s.day,s.instructor_change,s.studio_change,s.time_change,s.new_class,s.reservation_req,s.easy_does_it,s.mind,s.level,s.duration,s.location,i.first,i.last,a.first as alt_first,a.last as alt_last');
            $this->db->from('schedule as s');
            $this->db->join('instructors as i', 'i.id = s.instructor_id','left');
            $this->db->join('instructors as a', 'a.id = s.alt_instructor_id','left');
            $this->db->join('classes as c', 'c.id = s.class_id');
            $this->db->where('s.active', '1');
            $this->db->where('s.day', $dayofweek);
            $this->db->order_by('s.time',"ASC");

            $query = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just alias it differently:

```
$this->db->join('instructors as ialt', 'ialt.id = s._alt_instructor_id');
```

Comment: when calling it I am using a LEFT join, since this ID may be null. When I put this into the SELECT, when I try to alias this, i get a undefined index on the alias name

Comment: I was able to get it with your help, i had a comma out of place in the select statement

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('jobs');
    $this->db->join('company','company.cmp_name = jobs.cmp_name');
    $this->db->where('company.location', $data['location']);**strong text**
```