# joining the same table twice for different columns

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

i have one table products and one table locations. products table have two columns pickLocation and recLocation. in locations table i have id and name columns. pickLocation and recLocation have id from location table. how can i join table in codeigniter.

Here is my code

```
$this->db->select("locations.name as plname");
$this->db->select("locations.name as rcname");
$this->db->join("locations","locations.id=products.pickLocation","LEFT");
$this->db->join("locations","locations.id=products.recLocation","LEFT");
```

Here is Products table

```
+----+--------------+-------------+
| Id | pickLocation | recLocation |
+----+--------------+-------------+
|  1 |           12 |          23 |
|  2 |           12 |          12 |
+----+--------------+-------------+
```

Here is Location table

```
+----+-----------+--+
| Id |   name    |  |
+----+-----------+--+
| 12 | Location1 |  |
| 23 | Location2 |  |
+----+-----------+--+
```

I want result like this

```
+-----------------------+
| 1 Location1 Location2 |
+-----------------------+
| 2 Location1 Location1 |
+-----------------------+
```

Comment: you can use aliases for joined tables.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple SQL Joins from same table with Codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950760/multiple-sql-joins-from-same-table-with-codeigniter)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use aliases. Also, your product table never appears except in the join clause. It should also be in the from.

```
$query = $this->db->select("p.id, l1.name as plname, l2.name as rcname")
                 ->join("location l1", "l1.id = p.pickLocation", "left")
                 ->join("location l2", "l2.id = p.recLocation", "left")
                 ->get("product p");
```

Comment: The most elegant solution. Thanks!

Comment: Is this same as ->join('table as alias','condition') ?

Comment: yes, it's the same

Answer (score 2):

You need to use aliases, to be able to distinguish between these two joins. Try something like this:

```
$this->db->select("pickLoc.name as plname");
$this->db->select("recLoc.name as rcname");
$this->db->join("locations as pickLoc","pickLoc.id=products.pickLocation","LEFT");
$this->db->join("locations as recLoc","recLoc.id=products.recLocation","LEFT");
```